# C#: автоматическое скрытие строк в datagridview при загрузки из DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, события

Есть datagridview и DataSource, который я привязываю к datagridview.

Мне нужно , что бы все строчки, которые загрузятся из DataSource были скрытыми.

Я попытался воспользоваться событием:

```
        private void dgvTasks_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvTasks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Visible = false;
    }
```

Но почему-то, оно возникает только 2 раза, хотя добавляется строчек 500.

В итоге большая часть строчек видима...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие срабатывает один раз для набора строк, и не важно сколько их.
В е Вам передают индекс первой добавленной строки и их общее количество,
Вам остается пройтись в цикле по каждой строке и сделать с ней что нужно:

```
private void dgvTasks_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   for (int index = e.RowIndex; index < e.RowIndex + e.RowCount; index++) 
   {
      dgvTasks.Rows[index].Visible = false;
   }
}
```